# how to sync remote database from all local databases

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have created a windows application which interacts with a remote database(MSSQL). These client applications installed in different locations which do all transaction with the remote database. However, the application needs upgradation with more branches and the requirement does not end here. The client locations do not guarantee 24 hours internet connections. Sometimes the internet connection not available for 1 day. I have created local databases on all the locations where the client will interact to the local DB instead of remote DB. But I need to update all the recent(important) changes from local to remote for inter-branch manipulations.Here is the diagram
[image]

The updates will occur on click or automatically whichever possible. Please suggest me which architecture pattern I will follow.I have used local database cache but it only updates to local not remote. If replication then please share a link. Any other advice with link is appreciated
Client : windows application and ADO.NET (.NET framework 3.5 or 4 or 4.5 anything) 
Database : SQL server 2008

Comment: Did you checked Microsoft Sync Framework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Probably you need [SQL Server Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx). You can take a look at [SQL Server Replication Step by Step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/715550/SQL-Server-Replication-Step-by-Step)

Comment: This is not trivial and very broad. You'll have to do more research or outsource this. There isn't a concrete question, just "How to sync databases on button click", which cannot be answered in a few sentences.

Comment: The database needs to Sync itself, not have your code doing it

Comment: Also you need to conciser you database structure, if you create a new row in one of your local databases then you can't have another local database create the same Key, as you can't guarantee centralised key spawning then you need a Globally Unique Identifier(GUID) as the Primary Key on any record that can be generated non-centrally

Comment: if i am creating a new row in my local databases, then it is not required to create the row in other local databases except the central database @MikeT

Comment: @Ranjancode lets say you have 3 databases a, b and c and Central database S, to S is on row ID 10, the internet connection fails, so a user on a creates 5 records 11-15, a user on b creates 10 records 11-20 and on c creates 3 records 11-13, now the internet connection is restored to all new records are sent to the central database except that we now have multiple records all being written with the same Keys

Comment: I've actually been in exactly this situation, i had mobile staff that would sync a local XML file database with a central SQL database they would then work off of the local XML database until they could establish a connection to the central DB and sync all changes. if you don't carefully consider all situations (such as new records created simultaneously failed transmissions, failed confirmations, etc) then you will have no ends of trouble

Comment: This could be done by Micosoft Sync Framework... I too have same situation and completed by sync framework